# How to remove the border for Share button in Action Bar?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Have a look at the picture

[image]

This is how Share button looks like in action bar.

Here's the code I use in menu xml file:

```
   <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="Share"
        android:actionProviderClass=
            "android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

Is it possible to remove that border or change its color?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use custom background.

This might help:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html

Comment: Using custom background is not enough. This does not seem to work with transparent action bars.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complet message :

In your style, add

```
<style name="_MidipileTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

drawable/action_background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/background_actionBar"/>
</shape>
```

@color/background_actionBar is your custom background. For me, it's the same background color as actionBar background drawable.

Comment: This does not seem to work when using the transparent action bar (AppCompat theme).

Comment: @JoseGómez using the transparent action bar it will not work due to the color applied to the actionBarItemBackground is not transparent. 
Use `@android:color/transparent`as the `solid` color in the shape

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried setting the solid colour to a custom colour with value #00000000, and there was no difference (borders are still visible around the share button).

Comment: Did you specified the right Theme ? So if you don't see the change on the ActionBar it could be that the style is not applied. Maybe you are using Material Theme or something that is not `android:Theme.Holo.Light`

Comment: I am actually using Theme.AppCompat, as I want to support Android 2.3 onwards.